# FFMPEG: Calculation of image padding on video with different video source resolution

Tags: linux, ffmpeg

I have some video with different resolution (1920x1080, 1280x720, 1280,544, 640x480 etc)

What i need:

1. Cut video from 2 to 15 sec (+)
2. Change resolution to width equal source_video_height and height equal (source_video_height*1.777777777777778) (+)
3. Add some different text to video (+)
4. Change black padding to picture or create picture (source picture is 1800x1200) background to this videos (Right now picture overlay video, its not corrent) (-)
5. Create width and height padding with canculation as in point 2, I tried, but doesnt understand why can not use ih and iw there (-)

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i bg.jpeg -i video.mp4 -ss 00:00:02.000 -to 00:00:14.999 -vf "[in]scale=ih:(ih*1.777777777777778):force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=width=720:height=1280:x=(720-iw)/2:y=(1280-ih)/2:color=black,drawtext=fontfile=./DejaVuSerif.ttf:fontsize=30:fontcolor=white:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h)/5:text='Text_1':enable='between(t,5,8)',drawtext=fontfile=./DejaVuSerif.ttf:fontsize=30:fontcolor=white:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h)/5:text='Text_2':enable='between(t,8,10)',drawtext=fontfile=./DejaVuSerif.ttf:fontsize=30:fontcolor=white:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h)/5:text='Text_3':enable='between(t,10,12)'[out]" -c:a copy output_0_$RANDOM.mp4
```

Comment: How do you scale `bg.jpeg`?

Comment: its one one problems cause when i run command like this ffmpeg -loop 1 -i bg.jpeg -i video.mp4 -ss 00:00:02.000 -to 00:00:14.999 -vf "[in]crop=720:1280:0:0,scale=ih:(ih*1.777777777777778):force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=width=720:height=1280:x=(720-iw)/2:y=(1280-ih)/2:color=black,drawtext=fontfile=./DejaVuSerif.ttf:fontsize=30:fontcolor=white:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h)/5:text='Text_1':enable='between(t,5,8)'[out]" -c:a copy output_0_$RANDOM.mp4 I got error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `pad`. At first step do something with background, then overlay video.

```
#!/bin/bash
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i in1.png \
-i "input 1.mp4" \
-ss 00:00:02.000 -to 00:00:14.999 -filter_complex "
[1:v]scale=ih:-2[1v];
[0:v][1v]overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2:shortest=1,
drawtext=fontfile=./DejaVuSerif.ttf:fontsize=30:fontcolor=white:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h)/5:text='Text_1':enable='between(t,5,8)',
drawtext=fontfile=./DejaVuSerif.ttf:fontsize=30:fontcolor=white:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h)/5:text='Text_2':enable='between(t,8,10)',
drawtext=fontfile=./DejaVuSerif.ttf:fontsize=30:fontcolor=white:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h)/5:text='Text_3':enable='between(t,10,12)'
[v]
" -map [v] -map 1:a -c:v h264_nvenc -cq 20 -c:a copy /tmp/output.mp4 -hide_banner -y
mpv /tmp/output.mp4
```